# Remove or detach network phys interface attached to the LXC instance

Tags: docker, lxc

If I want to attach the network interface to the LXC we can specify it in the lxc config file as

```
lxc.network.type=phys
lxc.network.link=eth3
lxc.network.name=eth1
```

or we can run the below command as part of lxc hook to attach it during lxc-start

```
# on the host:
pid=$(lxc-info -pHn foobar)
ip link set dev eth3 netns $pid name eth1
```

Now I am looking for the option of removing or detaching the above attached phys interface from the container back to the host and how can I achieve it? I could not find anything in 'ip link help' option so far.

Answer (score 1):

If you have assigned a link to a network namespace like this:

```
ip link set dev eth3 netns $pid name eth1
```

Then you can simply re-assign that link to the global network namespace by running the `ip link set ...` command *inside* the target namespace, which you can do with the `ip netns exec ...` command, *if* you're using a "named" namespace.  If not, you are probably better off using the [nsenter](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/nsenter.1.html) command, like this:

```
nsenter -t $pid -n ip link set netns 1 eth1 name eth3
```

This takes advantage of the fact that PID 1 is pretty much guaranteed to be running in the global network namespace.